# Let $A: X \rightarrow Y$ a bijective continous map between two Banach spaces X and Y. Then, $A^{-1}$ is also continous?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, nonlinear-analysis

We know if A is a map continuous, bijective and linear then the answer is yes, $A^{-1}$ is continuous. But, if $A$ is no linear then $A^{-1}$ is also continuous  ?

Comment: Such examples must be infinite-dimensional (due to invariance of domain).

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space. Then the unit sphere $S\subset X$ is noncompact. Hence, there is a continuous surjective function $h: S\to (0,1]$. For $x\in X-\{0\}$ set $\bar{x}:= x/||x||$. 
Define the self-map
$$
f: X\to X, ~~f(x)=h(\bar{x}) x, ~~\hbox{if}~ x\ne 0; ~~f(0)=0. 
$$ 
This map is continuous and bijective but is not a homeomorphism: Take a sequence $s_n\in S$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} h(s_n)=0$. Then the sequence $(f(s_n))$ converges to $0$ while $(s_n)$ does not.

Edit. 1. If $X, Y$ are finite-dimensional Banach spaces then every continuous bijective map $X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism by Brouwer's invariance of domain theorem.

2. Every infinite dimensional normed vector space has noncompact unit sphere. This was discussed many times at MSE, see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287360/is-it-true-that-the-unit-ball-is-compact-in-a-normed-linear-space-iff-the-space?noredirect=1&lq=1).
3. Every noncompact metric space admits a continuous surjective function to ${\mathbb R}$; this was again discussed many times, see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932306/unbounded-continuous-function-on-non-compact-metric-space) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244557/existence-of-a-continuous-function-which-does-not-achieve-a-maximum).  Composing with the function $t\mapsto e^{-t^2}$ gives a surjective continuous function to $(0,1]$.